# Vs2008 c++ dragging the arrow of the debugger with keyboard

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

When on debugging mode, there is an yellow arrow that shows the next command to be executed.
Is there any way to drag that arrow with keyboard (rather than with the mouse)?

Thanks.

Comment: You can drag the arrow with the mouse? I never knew that. (Not sure how helpful it is, I hardly ever touch the mouse when I'm in Visual Studio...)

Comment: It's a fantastic feature! It means that you can force the debugger to go back and re-execute code or skip sections.

Comment: Or force entering to a conditioned section even though the condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my knowledge, not directly.

You can, however, use the keyboard to navigate to the statement you want to execute next, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to invoke the [Set Next Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) command.